# How do I install ec2-api-tools in 14.10 utopic?

Tags: amazon-ec2

```
$ sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ec2-api-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ec2-api-tools' has no installation candidate
```

Where do I get ec2-api-tools?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2APITools looks too old.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide also looks too old.

I would like to apt-get install these tools: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-user

Update: corrected the link to the tools I want. I want the python based tools, not the java based tools.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to answer my own question.

ec2-api-tools is replaced by awscli.

I couldn't remember the name awscli, hence my question.

It would be nice if the ec2-api-tools virtual package were updated to point to awscli package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

One can search

```
> apt search "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud"
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
awscli/bionic,bionic 1.14.44-1ubuntu1 all
  Universal Command Line Environment for AWS

libnet-amazon-ec2-perl/bionic,bionic 0.35-1 all
  Perl interface to the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)
```